# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{}?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, runtimeexception

Keep getting this error. Lurked around 20 different threads, all suggesting as:

1. Turn on a couple libraries in Java Build Path(they were already turned on)
2. Check to make sure my Manifest is currently coded correctly(not
   sure, will show)
3. Check my Java programming to make sure everything's in the right
   place and my intent is focused

My LogCat Error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MolConverter/com.example.MolConverter/MolConverter}: java.lang.classNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MolConverter.MolConverter" on path: /data/app/com.example.MolConverter-1.apk
```

My android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.molconverter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.molconverter.MolConverter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My Java code:
http://pastebin.com/kxUUt42L

Keep in mind I haven't coded everything so it's all a rough barebones. I just wanted to make sure my interface worked.

Comment: It's seems like `com.example.MolConverter.MolConverter` not found. cross check your .jar files

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild the project? (e.g. clean and build it again)? Could you post more logcat output?